# checking variable within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, collision

First time posting here, and first time creating a game in Javascript.

I'm trying to create collision between two objects in my game, a bullet and an enemy, but for now, just trying to make something happen with just the bullet, when it reaches the top of the screen.

When I press E, this happens:

```
if (69 in keysDown && timer == 0) //E
     {  
    var newbullet = Object.create(bullet);
    newbullet.posx = ship.playerx;
    newbullet.posy = ship.playery;
    projectiles.push(newbullet);
    ship.shoot = true;
     }
```

The bullet then moves upwards as it is stated in its update function.

I'm running this function constantly in my game loop, which checks for collisions, and that looks like this:

```
function Collision()
{
        for (i = 0; i <= projectiles.length; i++)
        {
            if (bullet.posy < 0 )
            {
                ctx.fillText("HIT" , 160, 340);
                ship.health -= 1;
            }
        }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I thought of substituting "bullet.posy" with "projectiles[i].posy, but it ends up saying that projectiles[i] is undefined.

projectiles is a global array.

```
var projectiles=[];
```

This is bullet:

```
var bullet = 
    {
        posx:0,
        posy:0,
        speed: 10,
        power: 2,

        draw: function()
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,100,0)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(((this.posx - 5)), (this.posy - 30), 10, 25);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        },

        setup: function(ax, ay)
        {
            this.posx = ax;
            this.posy = ay;
        },
        update: function()
        {
            this.posy -= this.speed;
        }
    };
```

Any help or advice?

Here is the [link](http://focserver.londonmet.ac.uk/cu4005-1415-25/Canvas2.html), if you wish to try it out
E to shoot.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the value of `bullet`? What is the value of `projectiles`? Does the value of `bullet.posy` change?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Can you create a quick demo with the issue?

Comment: Try changing `var newbullet = Object.create(bullet);` to `var newbullet = {};` or maybe `var newbullet = bullet;` would be better.  [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) expects a prototype, not an object literal, to be passed in.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++)

Comment: Good catch @Igor - I didn't even notice the `<=` in the loop.  That could cause a problem for sure!

Comment: var newbullet = bullet;

this worked! Thanks so much. :)

Comment: However now, each bullet I create overwrites the previous one, and also starts moving faster each time I create it.

Answer (score 2):

The first part <s>seems</s> seemed clear: A new bullet Object called `newbullet` is invoked with the value of the keys `.posx` and `.posy` being set by `ship.playerx` and `ship.playery`.  `newbullet` is then stored in the `projectiles` array.

The rest is not so clear. As you have it the if-condition of the for-loop in `Collision()` appears to be referencing the `.posy` of the `new bullet()` constructor, **not** the `.posy` of the object that's just been created (`newbullet`).  You'll also want to iterate the for-loop `projectiles.length - 1` times as arrays are zero indexed : so use the `<` operator and not the `<=` operator in the for-loop.

Assuming `ship.playery` assigns a number value, perhaps try assigning a variable to each item in the 'projectiles' array as it passes through `Collision()`'s for-loop...

```
function Collision() {
    var projLength = projectiles.length; // slight optimisation to for-loop
    for (i = 0; i < projLength; i++) {
        var thisBullet = projectiles[i]; // reassign variable each iteration
        if (thisBullet.posy < 0 ) {
            ctx.fillText("HIT" , 160, 340);
            ship.health -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: in light of updated question**

Being as you have the `projectiles` array in which to store your bullets, you can easily turn the `bullet` literal object into a contructor and make as many as you like/need/allow. Your code will then follow the description in my first para and look something like...

```
var projectiles = [];

var Bullet = function(x, y) {
    this.posx: x,
    this posy: y,
    speed: 10,
    power: 2,
    draw: function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,100,0)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(((this.posx - 5)), (this.posy - 30), 10, 25);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    },
    setup: function(ax, ay) {
        this.posx = ax;
        this.posy = ay;
    },
    update: function() {
        this.posy -= this.speed;
    }
};

/* --- */

if (69 in keysDown && timer == 0) { // E  
    var bullet = new Bullet(ship.playerx, ship.playery);
    projectiles.push(bullet);
    ship.shoot = true;
}

/* --- */

function Collision() {
    // as above ....
}
```

... it also means you won't have to wait for a bullet to reach `y < 0` before another can be created.  RAPID FIRE yay!!!

Comment: There isn't a new bullet constructor. He never wrote one. All he has is a single object literal. There's only ever one instance of it, which he's reusing.

Comment: Ah. OK.  I just assumed the new Object() had a constructor because he was storing it in a pluaralised array (projectiles not projectile), and I see the question has been edited since I started typing.

Comment: Yep. This is one of those questions where there's a lot going on.

Comment: Ignore the above then.  Whoever kindly upvoted it should probably downvote it now.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is difficult to work with, I didn't want to post the entire code. Everything looked like it was fine, until I tried to do collisions and stuff. If you want to see the whole code, it's here. http://focserver.londonmet.ac.uk/cu4005-1415-25/spacescript.js

Comment: Actually you know what, I think was wrong about the constructor thing. It looks like I misunderstood one of the comments above.

Comment: That is incredibly helpful. I assume I should follow the same format for every other object that is created, such as items and enemies? Thank you so much! @BrianPeacock

Comment: @Dimitri Xitas : Yeah.  Constructors are very useful in Javascript/html/canvas game programming. Some interesting and relevant info at HTML5 Gamer Development : e.g.  http://blog.sklambert.com/object-oriented-javascript-classes/

Comment: @BrianPeacock I have another problem now. In my game loop, I constantly run through all the objects in the projectiles array, in order to keep them drawn and moving. (Lines 626 - 630) However now, since I've changed the literal object into a constructor, I can't quite access their draw and update functions, in order to draw them and have them move. How can I access those functions now from outside? I've updated the code in the link I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: @DimitriXitas : You access functions inside a constructor (methods) with **dot notation**. I don't have the time to look through 1300+ lines of code but in at 626-30 you're referencing the `update` method of the `Enemy3` constructor not the `bullet` constructor.  Remember, every Object you create via a constructor is set with all the properties of that constructor.  See: MDN 'Working with Objects' : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects  Might be worth pinning the problem down and asking a new question. BP.